# Ruby on rails deployment with Vlad on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, vlad-deployer

I am having a problem with Vlad on windows. After calling `rake vlad:deploy` I am getting the following:
`uninitialized constant Fcntl::F_SETFD`

After googling for a while I figured out that there is problem with open4 gem that is not suitable for Windows and I should use popen4 gem instead.
I installed it but nothing has changed.

How can I force vlad to use popen4 instead of open4?

Comment: This is a bug. See here: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?group_id=4213&atid=16258&func=detail&aid=26816

Comment: This bug is related to JRuby. I am not using JRuby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Vlad* and *Capistrano* are not intended for *Microsoft Windows* systems. Even if you manage to get it running under *Windows* you will find new limitations. These tools are just nice wrappers (*rake* tasks) for automating *SCM*/*SSH*/*SFTP* tasks. I know *Capistrano* uses *xcopy.exe* to remotely deploy files but it is't as powerful as *rsync* or *scp*.

If you are still interested, *open4* dependencies are hardcoded on the source, the only way to get it running is by hacking the code.

*http://hitsquad.rubyforge.org/svn/vlad/2.0.0/lib/rake_remote_task.rb*

```
...
require 'open4'
...
##
# Rake::RemoteTask is a subclass of Rake::Task that adds
# remote_actions that execute in parallel on multiple hosts via ssh.

class Rake::RemoteTask < Rake::Task

  @@current_roles = []

  include Open4
...
```

By the way, using *Capistrano* will simplify you life but as advertised do not expect to take full *Capistrano* potential as it has minor support.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked on it . Some of the resources which may help you to solve your problem.

open4 will not work on Windows -- it is a Unix only library.For
Windows there is popen4.

[popen4](http://rubyforge.org/projects/popen4/) for windows

It does the same thing ... but for Windows. Be forewarned that the
possibility of blocking the program on a full pipe is very possible on
the Windows platform.

[Discussions here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/9379)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get capistrano working against a windows 2008 r2 box running [Cygwin's sshd](http://pigtail.net/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html) as a service, but not vlad's remote_task.  I wonder if remote_task can be ported to use Ruby's Net::SSH instead?

What I haven't been able to do is get windows to allow me to authenticate via public keys instead of passwords...